# How to get kubeconfig within a deployed app service

Tags: .net, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have an AKS deployment and I need to communicate with the kubernetes api. I have run the following code successfully on my local machine, after logging into azure and azure aks through the command line with my personal account:

```
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile(pathtomylocalkubeconfig);

_kubernetesClient = new Kubernetes(config);
```

However I need this to work in an app service inside azure, meaning I shouldn't use a kubeconfig with my own personal credentials in it. How do you programmatically get this to happen?

Also I would've thought that using my own personal one in azure would've still worked, but I got hit with SSL errors. What's that all about??

Answer (score 0):

You want `var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig()` instead. That will use the ambient configuration info available inside the cluster. Make sure your Pod has a `serviceAccountName` set and the ServiceAccount has the required RBAC permissions to talk to whatever APIs it needs.

Comment: I don't believe this will work. My app is not inside the cluster. It is a seperate resource inside the same azure subscription

Comment: I thought you said it was a deployed application? Unless you mean it's deployed on a VM outside of Kubernetes, in which case the simple answer is "don't do that, deploy it inside Kubernetes".

Comment: I don't want to deploy it inside kubernetes. I want to deploy it in an app service and then have the same control over kubernetes in my app service as I have through azure cli